# How to echo all 5 days count value in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
SELECT dateofbooking, count(id) AS total FROM participant WHERE dateofbooking >= $datepick AND 
  dateofbooking <= DATE_ADD($datepick, INTERVAL 5 DAY)GROUP BY dateofbooking;
```

How to echo all 5 days count value in php?

Comment: "How to echo all 5 days count value in php?" By reading PHP manual's myqsli or pdo..

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
$from = date('Y-m-d');
$to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("5 day"));
SELECT dateofbooking, count(id) AS total FROM participant WHERE `dateofbooking` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY dateofbooking;
```